# TableView can't scroll and swipe after adding a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to tableView using storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to tableView using storyboard to implement that long press the cell to jump to a new viewController.But the tableView can not scroll or swipe a cell to delete it.

I set tableView's gestureRecognizer to the longPressGestureRecognizer in tableView's connections inspector.Just drag it to the longPressGestureRecognizer.

However,if i just use the method addGestureRecognizer: in viewDidLoad: ,it will be all right.
It confused me.